# SQL - Condition to check for unique pair of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Need help with writing a query to sum total investment values in 2012(tiv_2012) to a scale of two decimal places for all policyholders who meet the following criteria:
1. Have the same tiv_2011 value as one or more other policyholders.
2. Are not located in the same city as another policyholder that is (lat, lon) pair mut be unique.

Here's my query but it doesn't work for part 2. (not located in same lat, lon):

```
SELECT ROUND( SUM(tiv_2012), 2)
FROM insurance
WHERE pid IN (SELECT i1.pid
              FROM insurance i1, insurance i2 
              WHERE (i1.tiv_2011 = i2.tiv_2011 AND i1.pid != i2.pid)
              AND ((i1.lat != i2.lat) AND (i1.lon != i2.lon))
             )
```

Would appreciate some suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
SELECT ROUND( SUM(tiv_2012), 2)
FROM insurance i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM insurance insurance i2 
              WHERE i2.tiv_2011 = i1.tiv_2011 AND i2.pid <> i.pid
             ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM insurance insurance i2 
                  WHERE i2.lat = i.lat AND i2.lon = i.lon AND i2.pid <> i.pid
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an EXISTS:

```
SELECT ROUND( SUM(tiv_2012), 2)
FROM insurance AS i1
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM insurance AS i2 
    WHERE i1.tiv_2011 = i2.tiv_2011 -- same tiv2011
      AND i1.pid <> i2.pid          -- different holder
      AND i1.lat <> i2.lat AND i1.lon <> i2.lon -- different city
  )
```

Comment: Thanks but the 'different city' condition still doesn't work with this. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63cbd3/12

Comment: @SrishtiSinha: Your expected result wasn't clear, but Gordon's answer should be what you need.